# How to give allowance to a contract and send erc20 between accounts

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, transfer, allowance

I wrote the following contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract enviaToken {

    address public tokenAddress = 0x;

    address public acc1 = 0x;
    address public acc2 = 0x;


    function giveAllowance() public {

        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        token.approve(address(this), 1);
    }

    function send() public {

        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);

        require(token.allowance(acc1, address(this)) > 0);

        uint256 saldoacc1 = token.balanceOf(acc1);
        require(saldoacc1 >= 1 ether, "Saldo insuficiente na acc1");

        require(token.transferFrom(acc1, acc2, 1));
    }

}
```

But when I call the send function in remix i receive the "insufficient allowance" error...

This is just a test contract, thats why I hardcoded the address (removed the hex here).

My MetaMask is connected to the remix, when I deploy, call "giveAllowance" and "send" a Pop-Up appears.

My acc1 has 100 tokens in Sepholia.

I searched everywhere, and always is the same answer: call the approve function to give allowance.

But even giving the needed allowance (calling the "giveAllowance" before transfering, successfully) I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

IERC20 has these two methods:

```
allowance(address owner, address spender)
```

You can call this function to set approval for the contract address as spender.

```
increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue)
```

You can call this function to increase allowance for the contract address to spend.

Transfer the tokens from account 1 to contract address, thus making the contract address the owner of those tokens then simply call function from within the contract address to transfer to another account.

```
transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
```